# How to extract column from cell (Excel, VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm running into a (run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error) error while trying to write my first Excel VBA Macro. I've looked at similar questions on stack overflow and other sites, but my issue seems to be more basic than issues others are having.

Currently, I'm trying to take the data from two cells from one sheet and write them to another sheet. I understand that trying to find the column or row of a cell that I reference by cell or row is unnecessary, but eventually I will use for-loops and will substitute the specific cell references with variables.

Here are the two lines of code that I have:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Row).Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Column & "1").Value
```

The first line runs fine. It writes Sheet1's A2 to Sheet2's A1.
The second line does not run, does not write Sheet1's B1 to Sheet2's B1,  references the error, and I'm not sure why.

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .Columns property returns an integer, not a letter. Use the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) if you want to define a range with a numerical row and numerical column.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Range("B2").Column).Value
```

I suppose there is a larger purpose to this but as it sits, it is very verbose code.

Answer (score 0):

your last lines from your question say that you want to fill Sheet2-A1 with Sheet1-A2 and Sheet2-B1 with Sheet1-B1

the most straightforward way is

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner at VBA just like you.  You don't need to know everthing in VBA to make productive use of it.  I made my first macro by RECORDING it, and it worked (but was hopelessly inefficient).

I had a problem similar to yours: looking up data on another worksheet.  I created the following function:

Function GetMyNumber(C3ll)
   MyCol = C3ll.Column
   GetMyNumber = MyCol
End Function

To use it in a spreadsheet, just enter the formula into some cell, like D5,

=GetMyNumber(D5)

When you recalculate, the number 4 appears in cell D5.  If you copy cell D5 into Cell F3, you will see in F3, =GetMyNumber(F3), and calculate will return a 6.  Of course you can fill down or across, the argument is changed to the cell the formula is in.  And if you want, you can offset with an argument referring to any cell.

Once you get this working, you can insert the code to do you matching and other tasks that make use of your column number MyCol to extract the number from the other worksheet.  Remember, MyCol is an integer.

Hopes this helps.